# What are the alternatives of Lusca in 14.04?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any alternative to Lusca in Ubuntu 14.04? I’m unable to install it. I receive this error message:

E: Unable to locate package lusca

What are the alternatives for that package, as I have come to know that Lusca is not available for Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Squid proxy server](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/).

I have never used Lusca but from what I read, Lusca is forked from Squid 2.

The latest version of Squid is 3.4. The 2.x branch I think it's not maintained any more.

Comment: i heard lusca does dynamical caches does squid do the same or i need to configure ACL for every website to caches content ?
if then where to find ACL parameters

Comment: Yes Squid supports dynamic caching. Below are some links with more information from their wiki's http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/Coordinator or http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube